# Throwing out minutes and seconds from time

Tags: mysql, time

I need to remove minutes and seconds for time stored in MySQL as TIME data type.
So 12:13:14 would become 12:00:00 and so on.

For now I have the following options:

```
SET @t = TIME(NOW());

SELECT
      @t
    , TIME(TIME_FORMAT(@t, '%H:00:00')) AS t1
    , TIME(CONCAT(HOUR(@t), ':00:00')) AS t2
    , SEC_TO_TIME(60 * 60 * FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(@t) / 60 / 60)) AS t3
    , TIME(10000 * HOUR(@t)) AS t4
;
```

The code would be in trigger and executed for a number of rows at once (not too many, may be a few hundreds).

My questions:

- Did I miss anything?
- What do you think is the most robust/efficient?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Looks like I missed MAKETIME function, so the solution would be `MAKETIME(HOUR(@t), 0, 0)`

P.S. I'm aware that the best way just store hour as tinyint unsigned. Unfortunately, I'm forced to store it as time for now.

Comment: All three methods seem reasonable.  What is your question?

Comment: If you're using the result in a `time` context, then `CONCAT(HOUR(@t), ':00:00')` is probably the most efficient, you shouldn't need to use `TIME` on the result as it is already a valid time string (the leading 0 on times earlier than 10am is not required).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, all would be in time context so TIME will not be in the code. I do not like the idea to create formatted string and force server to parse it. Anyway, looks like I missed MAKETIME function, so will use MAKETIME(HOUR(@t), 0, 0).